# How will I throw exceptions with stack traces in C++23?

Tags: c++, stack-trace, c++23

C++23 will likely see the introduction of a stack trace mechanism, via the [`<stacktrace>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/stacktrace) header.

I know we're going to have an [`std::stack_trace`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/basic_stacktrace) class, made up of `std::stacktrace_entry`'ies, and that is all fine. But - this won't be much help by just *existing*, because everyone would have to painstakingly make sure they always collect a stack trace and put it in the exception they throw. That is... not good.

Instead, what I want is for every (?) exception to automatically carry a stack trace, so that when I examine it or print it, or even when it gets auto-printed when not caught, the stack trace will be printed out.

Is this planned for to be possible, or am I asking too much?

Answer (score 7):

This is not a definitive answer, but there's a proposal [P2370: Stack Trace from Exception / Polukhin & Nekrashevich](http://wg21.link/p2370) for allowing basically what you want.
This was proposed in August 2021, and did not make it into C++23, but may make it into C++26 ([see GitHub for status](https://github.com/cplusplus/papers/issues/1056)).

It would let you write:

```cpp
try {
  foo("test1");
  bar("test2");
} catch (const std::exception& ex) {
  std::stacktrace trace = std::stacktrace::from_current_exception();  // <---
  std::cerr << "Caught exception: " << ex.what() << ", trace:\n" << trace;
}
```

There's a question of whether or not to turn this on by default. There could be something like:

```cpp
std::this_thread::set_capture_stacktraces_at_throw(bool enable) noexcept;
```

which you need to call to make it happen.

Comment: There is another modifying proposal, where you do not have to activate the stacktrace, but mark the collection of a stacktrace at the catch of an exception. Another advantage is that it is without overhead for the stacktrace (until collected). But also marked for C++26 (potentially).

Comment: Until now, I thought C++ as an old language with some baggage. Other languages would learn from the experience. But with the committee it perhaps is the other way round, C++ introduces features 10-20 years later and hopefully does everything right.

Comment: @Sebastian: Well, for library features, it's more like: You can sorta-kinda-get them for years, if not decades, and then at some point they get to the committee. Then you wait some more. Then eventually when you're old they get into the language and do what you wanted them to :-)

Answer (score 0):

As einpoklum said there is currently no way to do this for every exception object automatically.

But you can make a custom traced exception object that embeds a stack trace when thrown and use this throughout your code. This can be implemented with `std::stacktrace` or you could use a library like [cpptrace](https://github.com/jeremy-rifkin/cpptrace) which implements traced exceptions for C++11 and up.

Comment: I explained in my question why that's not what I'm asking about.

Comment: Hi @einpoklum, I've answered your question in that there is currently no way to do this automatically and also provided alternatives. When implemented right a traced exception object doesn't require the programmer "to painstakingly make sure they always collect a stack trace and put it in the exception they throw".